# Screenshot entire ScrollView content inside Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, screenshot, android-scrollview

I'm trying to take a screenshot of **entire** Dialog content but i'm facing some problems.
Dialog layout is something like

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- content here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My custom dialog class (implementing Dialog) is like

```
class PreviewDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // binding

        this.setOnShowListener {
            takeScreenshot()
        }
    }

    fun takeScreenshot(){
        var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            binding.scrollView.width,
            binding.scrollView.getChildAt(0).height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )

        var canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

        binding.scrollView.draw(canvas)

        File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            "TESTSCREENSHOT.png"
        ).writeBitmap(bitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85)

    }

    private fun File.writeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, format: Bitmap.CompressFormat, quality: Int) {
        outputStream().use { out ->
            bitmap.compress(format, quality, out)
            out.flush()
        }
    }
}
```

The result is not what i'm expecting.
Width and height of "TESTSCREENSHOT.png" are correct but the bottom part of image (the portion that is not visible on screen when i take the screenshot) is completely black.
What's wrong?

Comment: If you could use android java, enable drawing cache, build drawing cache then draw but with kotlin...

Comment: in any case, using drawing cache is deprecated